# KeyError when executing my code on youtube ape (multiple youtube ids)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, youtube-api

I have a problem when executing my code with multiple youtube ids and here are my code

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

api_key = 'AIzaSy...'

channel_ids = ['UCoUM-UJ7rirJYP8CQ0EIaHA' #Bruno Mars
               'UCqECaJ8Gagnn7YCbPEzWH6g' #Taylor Swift
               'UC9CoOnJkIBMdeijd9qYoT_g' #Ariana Grande
               'UC0C-w0YjGpqDXGB8IHb662A' #Ed Sheeran
               'UCBVjMGOIkavEAhyqpxJ73Dw'] #Maroon 5

youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey=api_key)

def get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_ids):
    all_data = []
    
    request = youtube.channels().list(
                part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
                id=','.join(channel_ids)
                )
    response = request.execute()
    
    for i in range(len(response['items'])):
         data = dict(channel_name = response['items'][i]['snippet']['title'],
                subscribers = response['items'][i]['statistics']['subscriberCount'],
                views = response['items'][i]['statistics']['viewCount'],
                total_videos = response['items'][i]['statistics']['videoCount']) 
    all_data.append(data)
   
    
    return all_data
```

however when i run the code its show this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndVux.jpg)

is there any solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```py
channel_ids = ['UCoUM-UJ7rirJYP8CQ0EIaHA' #Bruno Mars
               'UCqECaJ8Gagnn7YCbPEzWH6g' #Taylor Swift
               'UC9CoOnJkIBMdeijd9qYoT_g' #Ariana Grande
               'UC0C-w0YjGpqDXGB8IHb662A' #Ed Sheeran
               'UCBVjMGOIkavEAhyqpxJ73Dw'] #Maroon 5
```

to:

```py
channel_ids = ['UCoUM-UJ7rirJYP8CQ0EIaHA', #Bruno Mars
               'UCqECaJ8Gagnn7YCbPEzWH6g', #Taylor Swift
               'UC9CoOnJkIBMdeijd9qYoT_g', #Ariana Grande
               'UC0C-w0YjGpqDXGB8IHb662A', #Ed Sheeran
               'UCBVjMGOIkavEAhyqpxJ73Dw'] #Maroon 5
```

Solved the problem on my end.

Note the introduction of four commas.